# Why isn't a list of posts from my custom post type displaying in this widget?

Tags: custom-post-types, widgets

I have a custom post type called 'blog' . I wish to show a selected number of posts from this custom post type in a widget. But all I get is 'No listing found,' which is the else statements if no posts can be found. There are posts. What is wrong?

**My custom post type:**

```
function blog_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Blog',
        'singular_name' => 'Blog post',
        'add_new' => 'Add new blog post',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add new blog post',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit blog post',
        'new_item' => 'New blog post',
        'all_items' => 'All blog posts',
        'view_item' => 'View blog post',
        'search_items' => 'Search blog posts',
        'not_found' => 'No blog posts found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No blog posts found in trash',
        'menu_name' => 'Blog posts',
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'author',
            'thumbnail',
            'excerpt',
            'post-formats' ),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array( 'post-tag' ),
        'show_in_menu' => true,
    );

    register_post_type( 'blog posts', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'blog_post_type' );
```

**My widget:**

```
class Blog_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'blog_widget', // base id
            'Blog Widget', // Name
            array(
                'description'=> __('Displays the latest post excerpt')
            )
        );
    }

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['numberOfListings'] = strip_tags($new_instance['numberOfListings']);
        return $instance;
    }

    function form($instance) {
        if($instance) {
            $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
            $numberOfListings = esc_attr($instance['numberOfListings']);
        }else {
            $title = '';
            $numberOfListings = '';
        }
        ?>
<p>
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php  _e('Title', 'blog_widget'); ?> </label>
  <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('numberOfListings'); ?>"><?php _e('Number of Listings:', 'blog_widget'); ?> </label>
<select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('numberOfListings'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('numberOfListings'); ?>">
<?php for($x=1; $x<=10; $x++): ?>
<option <?php echo $x == $numberOfListings ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?> value="<?php  echo $x; ?>"><?php echo $x; ?> </option>
<?php endfor; ?>
</select>
</p>
<?php 
    }


    function widget($args, $instance) {
        extract( $args ) ;
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
        $numberOfListings  = $instance['numberOfListings'];
        echo $before_widget;
        if($title) {
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        }
        $this->getBlogExcerpt($numberOfListings);
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function getBlogExcerpt($numberOfListings) { //html
        global $post;
        add_image_size( 'realty_widget_size', 85, 45, false );
        $listings = new WP_Query();
        $listings->query('post_type=blog&posts_per_page=' . $numberOfListings );  
        if($listings->found_posts > 0) {
            echo '<ul class="realty_widget">';
            while ($listings->have_posts()) {
                $listings->the_post();
                $image = (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) ? get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'realty_widget_size') : '<div class="noThumb"></div>'; 
                $listItem = '<li>' . $image; 
                $listItem .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
                $listItem .= get_the_title() . '</a>';
                $listItem .= '<span>Added ' . get_the_date() . '</span></li>'; 
                echo $listItem; 
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            wp_reset_postdata(); 
        }else{
            echo '<p style="padding:25px;">No listing found</p>';
        } 
    }
}
```

What does it default to the `else` 'no listings found' ? There are posts available. Thank-you!

Comment: Any ideas, anyone please? It would be much appreciated!

Comment: You register your post type as `blog posts`, not `blog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it is a typo, but your custom post type name is incorrect, it cannot have spaces, and also you should just use underscores to separate names in custom post type names

```
register_post_type('blog posts', $args );
```

Is it just `blog` or `blog_posts`

In your query in your widget, you are querying the custom post type `blog`, which does not match your registered custom post type.

Last note, you should not use `extract()` at all. Look at the [Widget API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) on how to coreectly construct a widget

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo.  I will read up about `extract. Thank-you for the help!